# Hyper-V problems when wanting to run Docker from a macOS VM with VMWare Workstation 12 Player

Tags: windows, docker, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I am currently attempting to run a macOS High Sierra VM on my Windows 10 laptop using VMWare Workstation 12 Player.

To make the VM work, it says I must disable Hyper-V - Upon disabling, the VM does indeed work.

However, when I want to run Docker on my macOSHS VM, it gives the error:

[image: VMWare Error]

There is also a link to a page telling one how to work with Hyper-V and that it should be re-toggled to work, along with some CMD code that I can't seem to get to work...

When I **turn off** Hyper-V the VM starts as normal, but when I try to install/run Docker on there... I am greeted with:

[image]

Has anybody run into this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this answer, basically you have to enable virtualization in the vmware settings in the processor tab.

https://serverfault.com/questions/841330/docker-on-mac-on-vmware/849836#849836